# How does Jenkins handle parallel stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am executing some stages in my pipeline in parallel:

```
parallel {
  stage('A') {
    steps {
      script {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  stage('B') {
    steps {
      script {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am wondering how Jenkins handles this in the background and if there is any way to have influence on this. As far as I see, by default both parallel branches are executed in the same workspace.

I have 2 questions about this:

1. What would happen if you do a `stash/unstash` in one of the parallel branches (branch A)? Would this also affect branch B? (I assume yes)
2. Is there any (simple) way to make the parallel branches independent, e.g. for a case where something is modified in branch A that that you don't want in branch B or when both branches try to access the same files? I suppose that you can use `stash`before the `parallel` part and use separate workspaces for each branch, and `unstash`in those, but that's not really simple...

Answer (score 0):

I very like that feature from Jenkins.
But back to your question

1) I t runs in same workspace similar to multithreating. It means all file handler, environment variables same. Answer - yes affect

2) make the parallel branches independent
options:
- run in different folder
- run in parallel external job fully isolated. Put results into artifactory/s3/file storage. then re-use in main job. Quite nice scenario. easy to track fully isolated, separated log. But you has to store builds in external storage.

IMHO. I would prefer to have separate jobs. it's more easy from maintenance point of view. And you can reference to failed build in case of fail. to re-build only for part of job.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually your choice.

If you WANT the parallel branches to run in the same workspace, declare the `node` block before the `parallel` block. Obviously, be aware of potential concurrent file access.

Conversely, if you want the parallel branches to run in separate workspaces, then define the `node` block inside EACH of the parallel branches. That would normally mean you need to RECREATE your workspace, possibly doing a SCM checkout/clone AGAIN within each branch.
Alternatively, you can use the `stash`/`unstash` commands to transfer files between branches (e.g. if one (or more) branch(es) doesn't require a full checkout but just a small number of files) .

One additional node on the second option: if you use `node{}` or `node(<same labels>){}`, same as the original workspace, you will end up with the same original workspace. If you do that for both branches, only one of them will get the original workspace, the other one will end up getting a new (empty one. But AFAICT, it's not deterministic. So you're normally better off with being explicit.